# accessing value of next() and rewind() in a PHP iterator run in a foreach loop

Tags: php, object, iterator, foreach

Saw this in wikipedia, this is what happens when you traverse an iterator via a foreach loop:

> These methods are all being used in a
>   complete foreach( $object as
>   $key=>$value ) sequence. The methods
>   are executed in the following order:

```
rewind() 
while valid() {
    current() in $value 
    key() in $key 
    next()
} 
End of Loop
```

I was wondering how I can access the values of next() and rewind(). Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: Access them from inside the foreach loop

Comment: Why would you want to access them? This will throw off the internal pointer and could potentially end the loop prematurely / infinite loop it. It would make more sense to use them in a while loop sense if for learning purposes.

Comment: In the DB library I am using, I am planning to access the previous row and next row item from the query. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Probably. Which DB library is it? OR do you mean you're creating your own?

Comment: I am using KOhana's DB library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. To trigger a `reset`, you'd need to reenter the loop, and to call `next`, you need to go into the next iteration.

So the closest (PHP 5.3) would be this:

```
label:
foreach ($var as $k => $v) {

    /* ... */
    goto label; //re-enter loop

    /* ... */
    continue; //force going to the next iteration

    /* ... */
}
```

If you are using iterators directly, you can use those calls:

```
$r = 0; $s = 0;
$it = new ArrayIterator(array("a" => 3, "b" => 5, "c" => 7));
foreach ($it as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k => $v\n";
    if ($s == 0) {
        $s = 1;
        $it->next(); //jump over one iteration
    } else if ($r == 0) {
        $r = 1;
        $it->rewind();
    }
}
```

gives:

```
a => 3
c => 7
b => 5
c => 7
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about it?

```
for ($i =0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

    $last = ($i == 0) ? null : $arr[$i-1];
    $next = (isset($arr[$i+1]) ? $arr[$i+1] : null;
    $current = $arr[$i];

    //...

}
```

Comment: Won't work in general (the keys may not be integers, or they may not start with 0 and be sequential).

Answer (score 0):

IF its implementing the `Iterator` interface you can call those method yourself but they have implications.

`rewind` and `next` both set the position of the pointer in the dataset being iterated over... they dont actually return the element or index. So calling either of these is going to screw up your loop.

`current` will return the same variable you already have in the loop - ie. the element for the current iteration. `key` will return the index for that item in the set.